# Why can't ListView delegate refer to properties of ListView?

Tags: qt, listview, properties, qml

If a ListView contains user-defined properties, these properties can be referenced in a binding for `model` but they can *not* for anything inside the delegate.  Why is this?

[The docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) seem to say that a Component should be able see properties in enclosing scopes where it was declared.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible:true

    ListView {
        orientation: ListView.Vertical; height: 300; width: 100

        property var myCount: 3
        property var myMessage: "Hello"

        Component {
          id: myComp
          Text {text: myMessage} // ReferenceError: myMessage is not defined
        }
        model: myCount // this works
        delegate: myComp
    }       
}
```

(In my real application, the ListView is a component (.qml file) and the invoker needs to pass in information needed to configure the delegate; not
literal text like in this example, but information for a nested ListView.)

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

The variables in QML have a scope, in your case when using myMessage without reference these indicating that the variable belongs to the Text item.

```
# ...
Component {
    id: myComp
    Text {text: myMessage} 
}
# ...
```

So the solution is to use the ListView id as a reference:

```
# ...
ListView {
    id: lv
    orientation: ListView.Vertical; height: 300; width: 100
    property var myCount: 3
    property var myMessage: "Hello"
    Component {
      id: myComp
      Text {text: lv.myMessage} 
    }
    model: myCount // this works
    delegate: myComp
}
# ...
```